# How to configure NGINX with Memcached to serve HTML

Tags: performance, memcached, nginx

I'm trying to configure **NGINX** with **Memcached** to serve *HTML*

I found the following Memcached module for NGINX:

http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpMemcachedModule

But I can't seem to get NGINX to serve my HTML (e.g. index.html) files from Memcached from reading the tutorial above.

Anyone know what the NGINX config should be to bet it to serve HTML from Memcached?

Comment: The link is dead, maybe this is the same? http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_memcached_module.html

Answer (score 8):

To use memcached with nginx like this you will need to populate memcached with the right key/value pairs. To do this you will need the @fallback location to do some work for you.

When a matching request comes in, nginx will query memcached with whatever you set $memcache_key to. If the value is found it is sent to the browser. If not the fallback location invokes your backend system to do two things:

1. generate a response and send it back to the browser.
2. send the response to memcached and set the appropriate key/value pair.

The next time a request comes in for the same key it will be in memcached and will be served directly from there.

Comment: man, i was totally wondering why my nginx+memcached would seem stuck... and I was just missing the @fallback rule in my nginx conf file!  +1

Comment: Could you add more details? an example configuration would help. And are there any extra debian packages to install?